# Bootstrap datepicker reset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to reset the position of my datepicker calendar to today's date, and nothing works.

Among other things, I have tried

$('#selector').datepicker('setDate', '2014-01-01');

It looks like every function I call gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker, I think is version 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are going wrong, but given this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my-date-picker">
```

You can either set the date with a string like this:

```
$('#my-date-picker').datepicker('setValue', '01/02/2014');
```

Or you can use a `Date` object and get today's date, or any other for that matter:

```
$('#my-date-picker').datepicker('setValue', new Date());
```

Check out [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4y4sx3m/)